# Set image on left side of dialog

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I created this very simple example for JavaFX alert dialog for JavaFX8u40.

```
public class MainApp extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Button create = new Button("Create Alert");
        create.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Create an Alert Dialog"));
        create.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            createAlert();
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(create));
        primaryStage.show();

        stage = primaryStage;
    }

    protected Alert createAlert()
    {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
        Image image1 = new Image("http://www.mcaprojecttraining.com/images/java-big-icon.png");

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image1);

        alert.setGraphic(imageView);
        alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        alert.initOwner(stage);
        alert.getDialogPane().setContentText("Some text");

        alert.showAndWait()
            .filter(response -> response == ButtonType.OK)
            .ifPresent(response -> System.out.println("The alert was approved"));

        return alert;
    }

}
```

I'm interested how I can set the image on the left side of the dialog.

Did someone manage to change the side of the image?

[image]

Comment: Screenshot ? Which image ?

Comment: Please post code that other people can run. No-one has access to your image file.

Comment: why the javafx-2 tag? It's new api in 8u40, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a look at how the header is constructed, you'll find a `GridPane` node to layout a `Label` on the left and a `StackPane` for the icon.

If you want to reverse the cells order by code, you can do it, but it will be overriden every time `updateHeaderArea()` is called.

My suggestion is using this public API:

```
dialogPane.setHeader(Node header);
dialogPane.setGraphic(Node graphic);
```

providing a `header` with an icon on the left and a label, and a null graphic.

Using the same approach as `DialogPane`, we could add another `GridPane` as header:

```
protected Alert createAlert(){
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);

    alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    alert.initOwner(stage);
    alert.getDialogPane().setContentText("Some text");

    DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    ColumnConstraints graphicColumn = new ColumnConstraints();
    graphicColumn.setFillWidth(false);
    graphicColumn.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);
    ColumnConstraints textColumn = new ColumnConstraints();
    textColumn.setFillWidth(true);
    textColumn.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    grid.getColumnConstraints().setAll(graphicColumn, textColumn);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(5));

    Image image1 = new Image("http://www.mcaprojecttraining.com/images/java-big-icon.png");
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image1);
    imageView.setFitWidth(64);
    imageView.setFitHeight(64);
    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(imageView);
    stackPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.add(stackPane, 0, 0);

    Label headerLabel = new Label("Warning");
    headerLabel.setWrapText(true);
    headerLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    headerLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    headerLabel.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    grid.add(headerLabel, 1, 0);

    dialogPane.setHeader(grid);
    dialogPane.setGraphic(null);

    alert.showAndWait()
        .filter(response -> response == ButtonType.OK)
        .ifPresent(response -> System.out.println("The alert was approved"));

    return alert;
}
```

And this is what you will see:

[image: Alert]